# How can I change my expression to force a call to RewriteRuleSubtreeStream.NextTree() in the generated parser?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm an ANTLR novice that's trying to update an early ANTLR 3.1 grammar to 3.4. The one stumbling block I'm hitting is with my generated parser. There's a line of code that calls NextNode(), and I want it to call NextTree() instead, so my parser performs the desired behavior.

My ANTLR expression in question is:

```
cast    :   ('('  ssisType (',' INT)* ')') term -> ^(CAST ^( ssisType INT*) term)
;
```

ssisType is defined as:

```
ssisType
:

(   typeCode  ='DT_I1'
|   typeCode  ='DT_I2'
|   typeCode  ='DT_I4'
|   typeCode  ='DT_I8'
|   typeCode  ='DT_R4'
|   typeCode  ='DT_R8'
|   typeCode  ='DT_CY'
|   typeCode  ='DT_DATE'
|   typeCode  ='DT_BOOL'
|   typeCode  ='DT_NUMERIC'
|   typeCode  ='DT_DECIMAL'
|   typeCode  ='DT_UI1'
|   typeCode  ='DT_UI2'
|   typeCode  ='DT_UI4'
|   typeCode  ='DT_UI8'
|   typeCode  ='DT_GUID'
|   typeCode  ='DT_BYTES'
|   typeCode  ='DT_STR'
|   typeCode  ='DT_WSTR'
|   typeCode  ='DT_DBDATE'
|   typeCode  ='DT_DBTIME'
|   typeCode  ='DT_DBTIME2'
|   typeCode  ='DT_DBTIMESTAMP'
|   typeCode  ='DT_DBTIMESTAMP2'
|   typeCode  ='DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET'
|   typeCode  ='DT_FILETIME'
|   typeCode  ='DT_IMAGE'
|   typeCode  ='DT_TEXT'
|   typeCode  ='DT_NTEXT') -> ^(SSISTYPE $typeCode)
```

In my parser (in C#), the generated portion of code that processes the right hand side of the expression is:

```
    retval.Tree = root_0; 
    RewriteRuleSubtreeStream stream_retval=new RewriteRuleSubtreeStream(adaptor,"rule retval",retval!=null?retval.Tree:null);

        root_0 = (CommonTree)adaptor.Nil();
        // 99:44: -> ^( CAST ^( ssisType ( INT )* ) term )
        {
            DebugLocation(99, 47);
            // SsisGrammar.g:99:47: ^( CAST ^( ssisType ( INT )* ) term )
            {
            CommonTree root_1 = (CommonTree)adaptor.Nil();
            DebugLocation(99, 49);
            root_1 = (CommonTree)adaptor.BecomeRoot((CommonTree)adaptor.Create(CAST, "CAST"), root_1);

            DebugLocation(99, 54);
            // SsisGrammar.g:99:54: ^( ssisType ( INT )* )
            {
            CommonTree root_2 = (CommonTree)adaptor.Nil();
            DebugLocation(99, 57);
            root_2 = (CommonTree)adaptor.BecomeRoot(stream_ssisType.NextNode(), root_2);

            DebugLocation(99, 66);
            // SsisGrammar.g:99:66: ( INT )*
            while ( stream_INT.HasNext )
            {
                DebugLocation(99, 66);
                adaptor.AddChild(root_2, stream_INT.NextNode());

            }
            stream_INT.Reset();

            adaptor.AddChild(root_1, root_2);
            }
            DebugLocation(99, 72);
            adaptor.AddChild(root_1, stream_term.NextTree());

            adaptor.AddChild(root_0, root_1);
            }

        }
```

I'm looking for a way to change my expression so that

```
root_2 = (CommonTree)adaptor.BecomeRoot(stream_ssisType.NextNode(), root_2);
```

becomes

```
root_2 = (CommonTree)adaptor.BecomeRoot(stream_ssisType.NextTree(), root_2);
```

The reason is that the Tree's top node contains Children that aren't being added using NextNode.

Is there I way I can change the expression to produce my desired behavior? I've tried inserting an ^ at several spots within the expression but either the wrong result is generated or the grammar won't build.

Thanks very much,

-Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that AFAIK: what you place directly after the `^(` (the root) will always be considered  a single node, no tree.

An slightly different way:

```
cast
 : ('('  ssisType (',' INT)* ')') term -> ^(CAST ^(SSISTYPE ssisType INT*) term)
 ;

ssisType
 : 'DT_I1'
 | 'DT_I2'
 // ...
 ;
```

which will parse the input:

```
(DT_I2, 42, 666)123456
```

into the following AST:

[image]